# Truncating longer text and appending "..." to it, is not working in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am building a react app I have a long text in `.map` response which I am trying to truncate using `split` and `slice` method and adding **...** at the last to the long text. But It is not working after so many modified  truncate functions.

```
function truncate(text) {
  const words = text.split(' ');
  const truncated = words.slice(0, 30).join(' ');

  if (words.length > 30) {
    return `${truncated}...`;
  }

  return truncated;
}


function Blogs(props) {


   return (
         <>
             {props.blogs.map((res) => <>
                <div>
                      {truncate(res.title)}
                <div/>
              </>}
         </>
    
    )
}
```

I have also tried by modifying the `truncate` function like.

```
function truncate(text) {
  const words = text.split(' ');
  const truncated = words.slice(0, 30).join(' ');
  if (words.length > 30) {
    return truncated + '...';
  }
  return truncated;
}
```

It is not working after all.

Any help would be much Appreicated. Thank You

Comment: When I test this it is working though? It is doing exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: I don't why it is not working in my app

Comment: Please show the input that it's not working with, as well as the expected output.

Comment: Could you add how you're using the `Blogs` component?

Comment: It is showing full text when I try to print before returning

Comment: It is truncating titles after 30 words, which is a pretty long title. Perhaps you're testing it with shorter titles?

Comment: Thanks for you all for the suggestions. Now I know why it was not working. I put texts without any space like "54kjrgk526265" while testing and debugging, but it was made to work on text with spaces